# Inequality $x^4+y^4+(x^2+1)(y^2+1)\ge x^3(1+y) +y^3(1+x)+x+y$ for $x,y \in\mathbb{R}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Prove for $x,y \in\mathbb{R}$ that such inequality exists ;

$x^4+y^4+(x^2+1)(y^2+1)\ge x^3(1+y) +y^3(1+x)+x+y$

And here is what I realised ;
because $(x^2+1)(y^2+1) >=1$

and $x^4+y^4 \ge 0$

$1\ge x^3(1+y) +y^3(1+x)+x+y$

I'd prefer a hint

Comment: You will need to find tighter inequalities to use, in particular try finding inequalities which maintain the same equality conditions, viz. $x=y=1$

Comment: $1\ge x^3(1+y) +y^3(1+x)+x+y$ is this even true?

Comment: I very much doubt that.  Try $x=y=1$ for e.g.

Comment: Macavity's hint is really apt. I'd just add a spoiler to that, the Am-Gm inequality with $\frac{1}{2}(a+b) \ge \sqrt{ab}$ might come handy in here. Try combining different terms from the lhs with Am-Gm and see if you can get terms from rhs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** First expand the inequality. Then expand $(x-y)^4$ and use it to get rid of the $x^3y+xy^3$ terms. Beat the rest with repeated usages of AM-GM in the form $a^2+b^2\ge 2ab$ with various choices of $a,b$.

---

**A short solution**: It's equivalent to
$$\frac14(x-y)^4+\frac14(x^2-y^2)^2+\frac12(x^2+1)(x-1)^2+\frac12(y^2+1)(y-1)^2,$$
which is obviously greater or equal to zero.

**More detail**:
After expanding the terms and multiplying by 2, your inequality becomes
$$2x^4+2y^4+2x^2y^2+2x^2+2y^2+2\ge 2x^3y+2xy^3+2x^3+2y^3+2x+2y$$

Note that $(x-y)^4+(x^2-y^2)^2\ge 0\implies x^4+y^4+2x^2y^2\ge 2x^3y+2xy^3$, so it suffices to show
$$x^4+y^4+2x^2+2y^2+2\ge 2x^3+2y^3+2x+2y$$
We have $(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2\ge 0\implies x^2+y^2+2\ge 2x+2y$, so it reduces to
$$x^4+y^4+x^2+y^2\ge 2x^3+2y^3\iff x^2(x-1)^2+y^2(y-1)^2\ge 0$$

Comment: (+1) the OP asked for a hint though :-)

Comment: ah! I wasn't compaining ;) I had the idea $x^4+x^2y^2 \ge 2x^3y$, $x^4+x^2 \ge 2x^3$,$x^2+1 \ge 2x$ and symmetrically those for $y$ and add the 6 inequalities up:)

Comment: @r9m That's also nice, it was this one simple AM-GM all the way through :) But you are right, so I added what I proposed.

Comment: @user2345215 I have one more question -how did you realised that $(x-y)^4+(x^2-y^2)^2\ge 0\implies x^4+y^4+2x^2y^2\ge 2x^3y+2xy^3$

Comment: @II It's in the hint. $(x-y)^4=x^4-4x^3y+6x^2y^2-4xy^3+y^4$, so it's actually better to multiply by $4$ to get rid of $x^3y+xy^3$, and then there's extra $2x^2y^2$ and you can use $x^4+y^4$ to get rid of it. I condensed these two steps in one in which I only multiply by $2$. But there's another way to see this, as pointed out by r9m, just note that $x^4+x^2y^2\ge 2x^3y \iff (x^2-xy)^2\ge 0$, so it also follows from $(x^2-xy)^2+(y^2-xy)^2\ge 0$, which is probably simpler.